# Objective-c date difference confusion

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I'm trying to get the number of days between two dates and my logic seems to work fine for a wide range of dates - say August 12, 2012 - August 12, 2013 - it returns 364 days, 365 if I include the end day in the calculation. However, if I plug in August 8, 2013 - August 12, 2013 I get 0, or 1 if adding the end day to the calculation. Not sure what I am doing wrong here:

```
NSString* strNow = @"August 12, 2013";
NSString* strThen = @"August 8, 2012";

NSString* strNumOfDays = [dateManager getDateDifference:strThen :strNow];
```

method

```
- (NSString*) getDateDifference : (NSString*) startDate : (NSString*) endDate {

    //convert strings to dates
    NSDate* dateStart = [self convertStringToDate:startDate];
    NSDate* dateEnd = [self convertStringToDate:endDate];

    //check to make sure the second date is later than the first

    //get the number of days between
    NSCalendar* gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:dateStart toDate:dateEnd options:0];

    //the plus one is for including the endDate in the count
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [components day]+1];
}
```

convert string to date method

```
- (NSDate*) convertStringToDate : (NSString*) strToConvert {

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:(NSTextCheckingTypes)NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];
    NSArray* arrDateMatches = [detector matchesInString:strToConvert options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [strToConvert length])];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in arrDateMatches) {
        strToConvert =  [self convertDateToString:match.date];
    }

    NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strToConvert];
    return  myDate;
}
```

@Wain - The conversion is working as expected. 
@Rob - I am using NSTextCheckingTypes because I do not know what format the date will be submitted as - it could be 08/12/2013, August 8, 2013, 2013 8 12, etc.

Comment: Are you checking the output of `convertStringToDate` and any errors it raises?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify `convertStringToDate`. You shouldn't bother taking the `date` from `NSTextCheckingResult`, converting it to a string, and then converting it back to a date. You should simply:

```
- (NSDate*) convertStringToDate : (NSString*) string
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:(NSTextCheckingTypes)NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%s: dataDetectorWithTypes error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

    NSTextCheckingResult* match = [detector firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    return match.date;
}
```

I'm also unclear why you're adding `1` to the date difference. I'd be inclined to just:

```
- (NSString*) getDateDifferenceBetweenStart:(NSString*)startDate end:(NSString*) endDate
{
    //convert strings to dates
    NSDate* dateStart = [self convertStringToDate:startDate];
    NSDate* dateEnd = [self convertStringToDate:endDate];

    //get the number of days between
    NSCalendar* gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:dateStart toDate:dateEnd options:0];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [components day]];
}
```

Note, I'm using the more common syntax of identifying the names of the parameters:

```
NSString *difference = [self getDateDifferenceBetweenStart:strThen end:strNow]);
```

Thus, doing this, I get the results one would have expected:

- August 12, 2012 - August 12, 2013 results in `365`.
- August 8, 2013 - August 12, 2013 results in `4`.

It's not entirely clearly why your routine returned what it did. It may have been your `convertDateToString` method (which you didn't show us), or your configuration of your date formatter (again, we don't know what you did there, either). But the above code doesn't require either of those and seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function :

```
- (NSDate*) convertStringToDate : (NSString*) strToConvert {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
    NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strToConvert];
    return  myDate;

}
```

Instead of your convertStringToDate function use this function.